# How to filter list of photos - android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to do this: Sort array of objects values (Date type) by today date, this week, this month and this year and i know how to sort array of dates in descending or ascending order using Comparator class, but i don't know how to sort array like i said, by today date, this week, this month or this year.

```
private void sortTopicsByDate() {
    Collections.sort(topics, new Comparator<Topic>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Topic o1, Topic o2) {
            return o1.getCreatedTime().compareTo(o2.getCreatedTime());
        }
    });
}
```

**UPDATE (Filtering list with photos which are created today)**

```
private List<Topic> getFilteredTopics() {
    List<Topic> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    Date now = new Date(); // today date
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar getCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(now);
    int nYear  = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int nMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int nDay   = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    if (topics != null) {
        for (Topic topic : topics) {
            getCal.setTime(topic.getCreatedTime());
            int year  = getCal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = getCal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day   = getCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            if (nDay == day && month == nMonth) {
                filteredList.add(topic);
            }
        }
    }
    return filteredList;
}
```

Comment: What is "this"?

Comment: show what you tried so far

Comment: What do you mean by "sort by today date, this week, this month or this year"? Could you add a concrete example in your question please?

Comment: What is wrong with your current code?

Comment: For example, i want to fetch some photos. And some photos are uploaded a week ago, some photos are uploaded today, some photos are uploaded a month ago and so on.. Now i would like to sort array i get by today date, and that means i want to get only dates in array which are equals to current date. That is for example if i want to see in my list only photos which are uploaded today.

Comment: Do you mean you want to `filter` your photos?

Comment: If you sort by date, your elements are sorted such that todays elements are together, this weeks elements are together, this months elements are together, and this years elements are together. In short, your *sort* has already done what you *ask*, though your latest comment would indicate that you're not actually asking about *sorting* at all, so maybe you should read your question again, then *edit* it to clarify what you really want.

Comment: Yes, i want to show in one fragment list of photos which are uploaded today, one other fragment list of photos which are uploaded this week and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With java 8 you can use the `streaming-api`to filter your topics by date.
Note that this solution does not include `start` and `finish` in the `filter`, if you want that you have to modify the condition in the `filter`.

```
Collection<Topic> topics = ...;
Date start = ...;
Date finish = ...;
List<Topic> filteredTopics = topics.stream()
    .filter(t -> t.getCreatedTime().after(start) && t.getCreatedTime().before(finish))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Why not `t.getCreatedTime.after(start) && t.getCreatedTime.before(finish)`?

Comment: @bradimus Your suggestion is obviously much better :-) I corrected my answer

Comment: And how should i initialize Collection?

Comment: This is the same `Collection` that you used for sorting, can be e.g. a `List`

Comment: Okay, got it. I'll let you know about results.

Answer (score -2):

`Date` implements the `Comparable` interface already, with a naturally ascending date order (i.e. year first, then month, then day of month). It sounds like you are after reverse order (i.e. today, then yesterday, then last week, etc.) If that is the case you can just use a reverse comparison:

```
Comparator<Date> reverseComparator = new Comparator<Date>(){
     @Override public int compare(Date d1, Date d2){
         //dealing with nulls ignored for purposes of explanation
         return -1*d1.compareTo(d2);
     }
}
```

This should sort more recent dates first.

Comment: An alternative is to use `Collections.reverseOrder()`

Comment: @JohnLeehey absolutely, and generally more recommended as well :) I chose not to in this case because I thought this was more demonstrative of the method.

Comment: OP said *"I know how to sort array of dates in descending or ascending order"*, so why are you answering with a (bad!) example of descending order? By bad, I mean if `compareTo()` happens to return `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, your code will fail. To reverse order, just flip `d1` and `d2`, as in `return d2.compareTo(d1);`. Anyway, you're not answering the question, so: *-1 (Not useful)*.